# Input mask razor

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu estou precisando de ajuda para incluir uma mascara de CPF e CNPJ com Jquery ou Js, para que ela troque automaticamente depois que eu clicar em um select, porem não estou conseguindo incluir a mascara dentro do razor que eu fiz.

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/maskedinput")
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#xCpfCnpj").inputmask("99.999.999/9999-99");

    });
</script>
}
```

```html
     <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.xCpfCnpj, new
       {
           htmlAttributes = new
           {
               @class = "form-control input",
               placeholder = "Cpf/Cnpj",
               type = "text",
               id = "xCpfCnpj"

           }
       })

        </div>
```

Aqui eu tentei de 2 jeitos diferentes para inicialização

Comment: Ah entendi desculpa, ja irei retirar e postar o código, obrigado por avisar

Comment: Você está validando na model também? O bloco de script JQuery, está no topo ou no fim da view?

Comment: No fim da view  e estou validando na model

Comment: [Required()]
        public string xCpfCnpj { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `.change` do `JQuery` para fazer a mascara mudar ao trocar de opção na lista.

```js
$("#doc").mask("999.999.999-99");

$('#docType').change(function () {
    if ($('#docType option:selected').val() == 'CNPJ') {
       $("#doc").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    } else {
        $("#doc").mask("999.999.999-99");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<select id="docType" name="doc">
<option value="CPF">CPF</option>
<option value="CNPJ">CNPJ</option>
</select>

<input id="doc" type="text" name="doc" />
```

Segue mesmo exemplo no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wurthmann/n1qsmbh0/1/

Quanto ao problema da mascara não estar sendo aplicada é referente ao seu `JQuery`. Ele pode não estar referenciado ou você pode estar renderizando seu script no lugar errado. Mas é difícil dizer só com o que postou.

Verifique no console do navegador se ocorreu algum erro. Se não ocorreu nenhum erro verifique no Source se as chamadas pro `JQuery` estão corretas e se realmente renderizou o trecho que deveria aplicar a mascara.